# gulp process terminated with code 1

Tags: javascript, less, gulp

I'm trying to compile a less file to css with Gulp. But it keeps giving me `Process terminated with code 1.` errors... Does someone know what this means and why it occurs? And how I should fix it?

This is my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');

gulp.task('compile less simple', function () {
        gulp.src('box-sizing.less')
            .pipe(less())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('output.min.css'));
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks right but you shouldn't use whitespaces in your task name declaration (https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulptaskname-deps-fn).

So try:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');

gulp.task('compile:less', function () {
        gulp.src('box-sizing.less')
            .pipe(less())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('output.min.css'));
});
```

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you very much! It solved my problem! :D

Comment: I had a similar useless error from my task runner, it ended up being because I was trying to run a task "copy:font" which should have been "copy:fonts". Stumbled upon that while checking whitespaces, so thanks!